# Find the type of the file/folder passed to the CLI in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-commander

I'm creating a CLI app and using commander to process the commands entered by the user.

```
program
.option('-i , --index', 'file ') // option for adding a file/folder
const options = program.opts();
if(option.index){ // do sth }
```

And the user can enter `node index.js --index "Silver Blaze".txt` or pass a folder `node index.js --index "my folder"`

How do I find out the type of the value passed (if it is a file or folder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fs` module for that.

**Example**

```
let fs = require('fs')
let stats = fs.statSync(/* Path to file/folder */)

let isFile = stats.isFile()
let isDir = stats.isDirectory()

if (isFile) {
  // File
} else if (isDir) {
  // Directory
}
```

[More information](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: Thanks this helped.
Though it should be fs.statSync(process.argv[3])

option.index just returns a bollean

Comment: Oh, I see. Modified the answer according to this.